# Did Matthew, Mark, Luke, or John write anything other than the Gospels?

Tags: gospels, john-apostle, luke, matthew, mark

Currently I'm studying Youth Ministry and have a New Testament class that has been challenging. One of the tips for understanding an author better is to read everything they've written.

Have these four written anything else that we know of other than the Gospels? Or were they only inspired to write the Gospels?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! For a quick overview of this particular SE site, the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) is helpful. And if you haven't already seen it, the piece on [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is helpful. We'll see what others think of your question, but it looks okay to me. Traditionally, of course, Luke is also believed to have written the Acts. But present-day scholars dispute the authorship of many of the New Testament books, including the Gospels. So it might be tough to give a solid answer.

Comment: If you're looking for the traditional answer, that's actually quite easy. (I should have included the other New Testament books attributed to John.) But by now you've already gotten two quick answers on that, so if that's what you're looking for, you're golden!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With respect to the traditional attributions, here's the simple list:

- [Matthew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_the_Apostle): None
- [Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_the_Evangelist): None
- [Luke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_the_Evangelist): [Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_the_Apostles)
- [John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_the_Apostle): [1 John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Epistle_of_John), [2 John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_of_John), [3 John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Epistle_of_John), and [Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation)

Modern scholarship, which typically rejects the traditionally attributed authors of these books, still generally attributes [Luke and Acts to the same author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke%E2%80%93Acts).  There is less agreement on the [authorship of the other books attributed to John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Johannine_works), however.

Finally, there are [some apocryphal works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament_apocrypha) that are attributed to these authors, but they are not part of the canon:

- [Apocryphon of John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocryphon_of_John) (2nd century)
- [Gospel of Pseudo-Matthew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Pseudo-Matthew) (7th century)
- [Secret Gospel of Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Gospel_of_Mark) (claimed by some to be a late forgery)

Answer (score 6):

The authorship of the New Testament is a not universally agreed among Biblical scholars. Many would not agree that Matthew, Mark, Luke or John actually wrote the gospels that bear their name. However I'll assume you want a fairly traditional approach if you are teaching youth.

There is one thing that is almost universally agreed among scholars and that is that Luke (or whoever wrote the Gospel of Luke) also wrote Acts. They have incredibly similar styles, and Acts refers to "my previous book", so its considered pretty much a slam dunk.

The other candidates are the three letters that bear the name of John, and also Revelation. They are traditionally ascribed to John the Apostle, who is also traditionally considered the author the the Gospel of John.

Neither Mark or Matthew wrote anything else biblical.

You might like to consider getting hold of a Bible commentary, which will give you all sorts of extra information about what is known about the authors. If you are studying at a college level, you should have several of these available in your library.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Luke mentioning his "former treatise" in Acts, it is noteworthy that both the Gospel of Luke, and Acts of the Apostles are written in letter form, addressing Luke's acquaintance, one Theophilus (Luke 1:3 and Acts 1:1). This works to verify that Luke wrote both books as he establishes his narrative being a record of events presented in chronological order, bolstering the faith of Theophilus and giving him greater understanding of what he believes and why. The two books together offer the reader one continuous chronology of major events in not only Jesus' life and work, but also in the first century growth of His Church as directed by Jesus "to be witnesses unto Jesus in Jerusalem and all Judea, in Samaria, and the uttermost parts of the earth." (Acts 1:8)